# What is a postpback request in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web, request

I'm new to web programming, recently started to learn asp.net. Could anyone explain to me what is a postback request and how it defers from simple (if I can call it so) request?

Comment: A [PostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx) in ASP.NET just means that the page is not rendered for the first time, hence it is at least the second roundtrip to the server.

Comment: As you are new to web programming, i suggest to not start having headache with the magic of postback / viewstate and instead of asp.net webforms doing asp.net mvc.

Comment: @gsharp actually I started with mvc framework, but now I'm reading about sessions and other asp.net platform features to retain state. Do You mean that in mvc there is no such a thing like postback??

Comment: No there's no postback in mvc... (and that's a good thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft tried to make web programming a bit like windows programming... it came up with webforms.  When you first get a page from asp.net you do a GET,  and you get a "webform" which is a webpage with buttons, text boxes, combo boxes, much like a windows dialog.

Now, microsofts framework has a bit of magic that you means you can configure a change ( like a button click, or change of a combobox ) to do a postback.  That means the browser will POST back the page with the changes,  it then translates these into events,  like text changing, or button clicking, or combobox changing.  Which you can handle, then it resends the changed page back to the browser.

So basically postbacks are triggered points where you can handle events on the server when using webforms.   This is not exactly how other web frameworks work.

Comment: can You give me an example of using callback in asp.net mvc app (mvc 3)?

Comment: mvc is a bit more open ended, it provides facilities to easily map GET and POST requests to "Actions".  The classic way of showing asp.net mvc is using HTML form elements and then they post their result on submit back to an "Action" that does model binding and validation.  It is then possible for the code to send the same page back to the user with errors highlighted or go to another page.  However other than when first playing with MVC, I don't use that,  I use knockoutjs and jquery ajax calls to do most of my server interactions. ( and now starting to do that using asp.net webapi )

Comment: a lot of the examples in MVC is with "Html Helpers" which is all about making binding form elements to model elements really easy.  That then makes model binding / validation easy. Very easy to think that is asp.net MVC and thats how you do things.   It certainly can be a really good way to do things,  but the MVC framework is quite flexible and there are a number of approaches.  In the latest 2012 web update, there are templates for SPA, which demonstrates another approach similar to the one I tak described above

Answer (score 2):

Simple request is 'give me page so-and-so'.

Postback request is 'give me page so-and-so (which I am already on) but when you **post** it **back**, change these data accordingly (which will be the result of the user selecting a combo box, or checking a radio button or whatever).

When you're coding asp.net you put all the stuff that happens in the first visit to the page in the `page_load` surrounded by a

```
if (!postback)
{
}
```

This ensures that code that should load when the user first visits the page doesn't happen when the user has set the above-mentioned options

Answer (score 2):

PostBack is the name given to the process of submitting an ASP.NET page to the server for processing. PostBack is done if certain credentials of the page are to be checked against a database (such as verification of username and password) or doing some calculation.

This is something that a client machine is not able to accomplish and thus these details have to be ‘posted back’ to the server.
`Postback` occurs usually when you click a `button`, `radiobutton`, `checkbox` or `any other control`(if you specify `OnClick` event in the markup). Many other event also call postback if specified in the markup.

**Note**: When a postback goes to server it also process `page_Load` event of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, there's this thing called PostBack. In a classic ASP.NET WebForm you could have only a single `<form>` element with `method="post"` inside the entire page. And everytime you click on a button that's inside this form or perform some action, ASP.NET will POST to the same WebForm. Thus the name PostBack. So basically you will use a GET request to render the webForm for the first time and from now on everything you do on this form will result in a POST request to itself.

In a normal web application, you could have multiple `<form>` elements inside the HTML. Each form could post to different endpoints, some using GET, other using POST requests.